# Redirect to another page by using the Content Editor Web Part is not working

Tags: performance, sharepoint

I am using content editor to redirect on a different page of a SharePoint 2010 site. It had following code:

```
<script '"text/javascript"'></script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://intouch/...">
```

Its working only for a specific group of users. I exactly don't know which permission level is working to it. I have Full control so its working well for me. Other users, who hava **Read or Contribute permission, does not work.**

Although I want to reduce time. It is now 1 sec (i.e. content attribute value in meta tag), can it be reduced?

In other words how can i improve its performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) you can set the value of the timer to 0 and it will redirect immediately.

Another alternative is to use the SharePoint page template "Redirect" which allows you to redirect to a specific URL without adding any code.  However, it may not be immediate, and it only works on sites where the Publishing feature is activated.